# There is no line here to end \makelettertitle error in moderncv

Tags: errors, moderncv

I am using `moderncv` templates, on cover letter page i wanted to edit the original code so that the Name/mobile/email appears on top right corner,
[image]
  but the Build process return the error:  `There's no line here to end. \makelettertitle` 
    Here is the location that error is happening, if i put any character in `\recipient{}{}` line such as `\recipient{'}{}` the error would be solved,but the character will be shown in the result,which i don't want it, i searched for similar cases but none of the solutions given helped, is there any solution for it if i don't want to use `\recipient` ? (I have tried removing it from the code but it didn't work) The code:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Smith} % Your last name
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\mobile{(+1) 123 456 7890}
\email{john.smith@gmail.com}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\recipient{}{} % Letter recipient
\date{\today} % Letter date
\opening{Dear Sir, Madam,} % Opening greeting
\closing{Sincerely yours,} % Closing phrase
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} % List of enclosed documents
\makelettertitle % Print letter title
I am an engineer

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

and the content of class file is:

```
\newcommand{\recipient}[2]{\def\@recipientname{#1}\def\@recipientaddress{#2}}
\renewcommand*{\date}[1]{\def\@date{#1}}\date{\today}
\newcommand{\opening}[1]{\def\@opening{#1}}
\newcommand*{\closing}[1]{\def\@closing{#1}}
\newcommand*{\enclosure}[2][]{%
  % if an optional argument is provided, use it to redefine \enclname
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\renewcommand*{\enclname}{#1}}%
  \def\@enclosure{#2}}
```

Comment: Please post a full document, not just fragments

Comment: A full document has at least `\documentclass{...}`

Comment: `\recipient{\mbox{}}{\mbox{}}`

Comment: thanks egrep , Kurt  and Christian , both solutions worked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class loads the auxiliary package `moderncvheadi.sty`, which has

```
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
```

and this means that if `\@recipientname` is empty, you get the usual error of a lone `\\`, that is `There's no line to end`.

Solution:

```
\recipient{\mbox{}}{}
```

which will make the line non empty, as far as `\\` is concerned.

Comment: My \recipient is not empty yet I still get this message.

Comment: @user134593 I tried the original code with `\recipient{x}{y}` and get no error.

Comment: It's really strange too because I used it on this exact PC with this exact installation and file before and don't remember an error. Perhaps it's a side effect of intermediary files, but I deleted the `.aux` file, and still no dice. Well at least it produces a usable PDF output.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, if you write an letter, you need a recipient.  If you want to leave the empty you have to mark the recipient empty.  The character `~` marks an unbreakable space and you can use it for your purpose.

So `\recipient{~}{~}` get's you rid of the error message `no line to end`.